# Odd UIBarButtonItem behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Try the following in the simulator or a device.

Create a new Master-Detail application for iPhone or compare any app that uses navigation bars. iOS 5 or 6, don't matter.
In the case of the template: Let it run,create an entry using the plus button and open the entry.

Now touch the area below the navbar directly under the UIBarButtonItem thats leads back.

Even when the button nor the navigation bar is clearly not touched, the button will activate and the view does return.

[image: Example]

This is way beyond the 44x height of the navbar.
What is happening here?
Why does this button respond way beyond his frame?
Cant find an info about this in the HIG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**iPhone**

The area you can press to activate the back button is actually larger than the actual pixels of the button to accommodate the average thickness of fingers. (The actual number of pixels is buried somewhere in Apples HIG. I think it is 44x44.) This is expected behavior.

**iPad**

The master view controller is automatically dismissed when you tap outside it. This is expected behavior.

Comment: Thank you. My iPad example was badly choosen, since the template does not use a Navigatinbar on iPad. However, the iPhone answers covers booth. Still looking for that line you mentioned in the HIG.

Comment: I was unable to find this in the HIG. Please have a look on the screenshot I did provide. The button blocks views/cells below that area since he responds to touches outside of the navbar. is this really working as intended?

Comment: Yes it is working as intended. If you put controls into the cell it will override this behavior and not trigger the back button. Try it out with a simple UIView.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Seems my custom controls fail to archive this behavior. Going to have a look on this when we redesign the UI.